# Write 8bit integers to a file

Tags: bash

I need to write 8bit integers to a file.
But in `bash` the default primitive type is string, so if I do it like this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 9); do
    printf $i | dd of=/tmp/f count=1 seek=$i bs=1 conv=notrunc
done
```

`printf` will write strings "1" to "9" and that is what the `dd` will pick up. But I need 8bit integers. And I cannot use constants like '\x1', because I need to perform arithmetic operations on the 8bit integer before it can be written.

Is it possible to force `printf`or maybe other command not to interpret the variable content as string, but as 8bit integer?

Comment: Please add your desired output in hex (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Why are you doing this in `bash`?

Comment: `for i in $(seq 10); do perl -e "print chr $i"; done | xxd`

Comment: `for i in $(seq 10); do python3 -c "print(chr($i), end='')"; done | xxd` or `python3 -c 'for i in range(1, 10): print(chr(i), end="")' | xxd`

Comment: OK, seems like indeed abuse of bash. Will try out Python for the task.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed-out, Bash or shell is a poor choice for dealing with binary data it has not been designed for.

This print from A to Z from ASCII value:

```sh
for i in {65..90}; do
  printf "\x$(printf %x $i)"
done
echo
```

Now with your sequence:

```sh
for i in $(seq 1 9); do
    printf "\x$(printf %x $i)" |
      dd of=/tmp/f count=1 seek=$i bs=1 conv=notrunc
done
```